# The following classes could not be found -android.support.v7

Tags: android-studio-2.1, xml-layout

I have just installed android studio and the following errors have just emerged on my xml layout file

```
The following classes could not be found:
-android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar
-android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
-android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
-android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
-android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
-android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

How do I remove these errors??

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to the problem...

Go to styles.xml in values folder and change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: However, the name of the app is not showing on the action bar and I would still like it to show.Somebody help here please...